# Executing a command based on a variable

Tags: powershell

I want to execute `WinRAR.exe`. The path of WinRAR is decided by a variable called `$a`. And I don't know how to correct the following code:

```
$a = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR"
$a\WinRAR.exe   # this line raises an error
```

I can see the value of `echo $a`:

```
$a = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR"
echo $a  # "C:\Program Files\WinRAR" is printed
```

And I'm sure that executing `C:\"Program Files"\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe` can launch WinRAR

Does anyone know why `$a\WinRAR.exe` is not working?

Comment: `& "$a\WinRAR.exe"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simple. You need to prefix the  call to winrar with an ampersand.

```
&$a\winrar.exe
```